# Using String from a dictionary in a ConverterParameter

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to use a `String` from a dictionary:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Dictionary EnglishName="English" CultureName="English" Culture="en-US">
...
<Value Id="ButtonSuppressFieldInformation" 
       ToolTip="Remove field" Name="Remove field number "/>
...
</Dictionary>
```

In this `ConverterParamter` to enable multiple langages support:

```
<Button>
    ...
    <AutomationProperties.Name>
        <MultiBinding 
                Converter="{StaticResource IndexedForAutomationId}" 
                ConverterParameter="{loc:Translate 
                      Uid=ButtonSuppressFieldInformation, Default=Delete field}">
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
            <Binding ElementName="MyContactDirectoryView" 
                     Path="ListConditionToSearch" />
        </MultiBinding >
    </AutomationProperties.Name>
</Button>
```

But the only thing shown is the number (`IndexedForAutomationId`), the `string` does not appear.

Using a `string` instead of `"{loc:Translate Uid=ButtonSuppressFieldInformation, Default=Delete field}"` works:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IndexedForAutomationId}" 
              ConverterParameter="Delete field">
```

Displays `Delete field 0`.

What is the way to use `loc:Translate` as a ConverterParameter?

Comment: What is `loc:Translate` here?

Comment: It calls the dictionary and look for the `ButtonSuppressFieldInformation` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue could be due to a lot of things and some more code would really help here. I would start, however, with a breakpoint on the `Convert()` method of the `IndexedForAutomationId` converter to 1) check if you get the values your are expecting from the inner bindings and 2) check if the converter itself is returning the right string from the dictionary.

Please make sure to review these guidelines about [how to debug WPF bindings](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/486) as well.

Comment: `IndexedForAutomationId` works fine, the issue come from the `{loc:Translate ...}` part.

Comment: Did you follow my suggestion and put a breakpoint on the Convert() method? What did you find there? Did it return the string you were expecting?

Comment: Finaly found it, the converter is unable to resolve a dictionary string as a parameter. It only sees `Uid=...` and it didn't use the default parameter. I need to make a call to the dictionary within the converter itself...